# How do I make a Commando bot respond to a message with a certain substring anywhere in the message

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

I'm working with a friend to add something to an existing Discord bot. There a number of working commands that use `discord.js-commando`, so we're tied to using Commando.

The guild we're doing this for has moved some resources from an old site to a new one, and we'd like to remind the guild members who link to the old site that they should use the new site instead:

```
// User123 says...
Check out https://www.example.com/.
// bot responds:
Hey User123! You should use our new site! https://www.example2.com/
```

The bot would only trigger if it sees `www.example.com`.

Here's the code...

```
// file: index.js
const bot = new Commando.Client({
    commandPrefix: './'
});

bot.registry
    .registerGroup('autoresponses', 'AutoResponses')
    // other groups
    .registerDefaults()
    .registerCommandsIn(__dirname + '/commands')
    ;
```

and the file I'm working on

```
// file: commands/autoresponses/messages.js
const discord = require('discord.js');

client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.bot) {
        return;
    }
    if (message.content.includes("www.example.com")) {
        var responseString = "Hey " + message.author + "! That's the old site! Please use the new one: https://www.example2.com/";
        message.channel.send(responseString);
    }
};
```

Trouble is, this doesn't use Commando, just regular discord.js. Is this even possible with Commando? Or do I need another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend on using `Comando` you'll need to work with the `Commando.Client`. The way your bot is set up is so you only need to add a command in the `commands` folder. Seems like `Comando` has a way to trigger on a regular expression.

```
let Command = require('Comando').client;
module.exports = class OldWebsite extends Command {
    constructor(client){
        super(client, {/* Your command config here */, patterns: [/website\.com/] });
        //patterns is a prop that accepts regular expressions to match on a message
    }
    async run(msg){
        return msg.reply('Hey that\'s our old webiste!');
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a [`Command`](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/master/test/commands/math/add.js). Here's the documentation of what can go into the [`CommandInfo`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/typedef/CommandInfo) (your command config).